# Voronoi summation formula with Dirichlet character

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Voronoi's summation formula says something like $$\sum _{n}d(n)e(an/q)w(n)=\sum _nd(n)e(\overline an/q)e(\sqrt {nx}/q)\hat w(n)$$

where $w(n)$ is a smooth weight function and $\hat w$ is some integral transform of $w$.

I would like a similar formula but with a Dirichlet character (of general modulus) in the sum as well.  But when I google around, nothing seems to come up.  My guess is, that my question doesn't really make sense.  Either it's not really possible, or it's a weird specificaiton.  I find lots of generalisations of the above formula but I don't know how to think of the general (Hecke/Mass/modular/similar-adjectives) coefficients that come up in that case - perhaps they contain Dirichlet characters.

Anyway, anyone who can sense what I'm missing and can give a few comments would be great.

P.S. I'm aware I could write the character as a sum over an exponential, but this leads to the RHS above being something like $\Sigma _b^r\chi (b)e(n(\overline a/q-b/r))$ and I'm not sure if I can do anything  with this.

Comment: The only strategy is to write the character sum as an exponential. The answer that you get may be quite ugly depending on the relationship between $q$ and the conductor of $\chi$.

Comment: hmm:/ well, thanks anyway, cause it's good to know that's nothing else is possible i guess...